# Why my filtered value in array using NSPredicate returns a repeated output?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

Hello there I'm new in IOS development and I'm trying to filter my array for my search function of my application. For now I'm getting a repeated output on my code here is my code;

```
 NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == '123456'"];
 NSLog(@"adsf %@", [myMutArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate]);
```

the log returns a 30 (123456) value I'm wondering why it is happen. I'm not running that code in any loop so I'm wondering.

Comment: What do you mean by "the log returns a 30 (123456) value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many “123456” objects are in your array? If it’s 30, everything is working correctly.

Comment: 123456 objects in my array is only 1

Comment: We’d have to see more of the code. And the actual log output.